How to print palindrome pattern without using any string method
I am currently stuck not getting how do I need to print the below pattern without using any string method or any string properties and not even any thing which direct or indirectly associated with string
Pattern
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321

I tried this but got failed as I am using sep is part of string
n=5
for i in range(1,n+1):
   print(*list(range(1, n + 1))[:i]+list(range(1, n + 1))[:i][::-1][1:],sep='')

I have one more which worked for me using square
print((10**i//9)**2)

Is their any other way apart this above code ... please share your input.

sep is part of the print, not the string.

Just out of curiosity: why would you want to do that? Is this a homework or interview question?

Why do you say you're stuck when your squaring method works?

It is impossible to print something that is not directly or indirectly associated with str. Whatever you print has to become a str some kind of way, and that alone means it is either directly or indirectly associated with str. Your wording implies this is a trick question, and trying to provide a solution is how you fail the question.

@OysterShucker What about writing bytes with sys.stdout.buffer.write?

@nocomment - I'm talking about the function, not the action. Also, bytes are indirectly associated with str, regardless if you find a fancy way to "print" them.

In this code, everything is done honestly, i.e. there is no concatenation, no square:
s = 0
v = 1
for i in range(5):
    s = 10*s + v
    v = 10*v + 1   # Can be simplified:
    v = 10*v + 1   # v = 10*(10*v + 1) + 1 = 100*v + 11
    print(s)

Here's how it works:

First you need to get the sequence (v)
Then simply accumulate by first shifting the previous value by one decimal point (s)

    v                       s

    1      +        0 =     1
   111     +       10 =    121
  11111    +     1210 =   12321
 1111111   +   123210 =  1234321
111111111  + 12343210 = 123454321


@nocomment, so it was your answer that flashed by and disappeared. I just managed to see that there is only one cycle in it. And I started thinking about how to get rid of the inner loop. This led to the same result as yours.

Yeah, likely. Code was this. I prefer *100+11, but I also prefer your order, printing last in the loop.

@nocomment, yes, this is the same code.

Below is the approach I used which is completely a loop based.
n=int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
       print(j,end="")
    for j in range(i-1,0,-1):
       print(j,end="")
    print()


a bit long but works, check if you can modify somewhere
def pal():
  n=int(input());
  res=[];
  res.append( [i for i in range(1,n)]);
  res.append([i for i in range(n,0,-1)]);
  for i in res:
      for j in i:
          print(j,end="");



pal();  


Sorry I forgot about the pattern I only answered the final outcome
below is the code for printing Whole Pattern
def pal():
  n=int(input());
  res=[];
  for k in range(1,n+1):
    if(k==1):
          res.append([1]);
          continue;
    res.append( [i for i in range(1,k)] + [j for j in range(k,0,-1)]);
  
  for i in res:
        print(*i,end="\n");
       
pal();

